# Is Online Data Entry/Typing a good way to earn an extra income?

Tags: scams, online

A friend of mine, working as a manager in a store, asked me if I could find him a job of online data entry, since he is having a lot of free time.

So I am looking for a job like :

- Data Entry
- Form filling/surveying
- Copy-Typing data into Word Documents

I googled a bit, looking for it that could be done online or offline. I understand that I may have to provide my details like name, age and bank account number. But they also require that I pay some registration fee.

I understand that some of them may be scam, that will ask you to pay for registration and then not have any work, so you wont get paid. While some may give you some work to do but not pay.

Is Part-time online data-entry job a good way to earn extra income, the way I see it most are just scams?

<strike>can you name some good Part-time online data-entry job portals that you know of?</strike> [I guess I could ask this question when [Web Recommendation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations) gets into beta phase]

Answer (score 3):

> Is Part-time online data-entry job a good way to earn extra income,

It depends, but yes its a good way to earn extra income. And its not limited to data entry, some are social engineering ... every wonder why you see so many good review about green tea? or any such product. You get paid for every positive / authoritative review you write.

> the way I see it most are just scams?

Yes. There are multiple different types of it. Some are sites with good intention, but are not able to generate the positive revenue that they anticipate and go bankrupt. Some are outright scams.

> can you name some good Part-time online data-entry job portals that you know of?

This would be out of scope here as specific product recommendations are off topic on this site.

Comment: thanks....i didn't know about product recommendations are off topic, i am going to edit my questions.....